# How to find the detailed document about Angular2 class

Tags: angular

Where could I find the detailed document about `KeyValueDiffers` class?
I found the official document about it is too simple and I still don't know more about it.
How do you master this class and those classes like it?

Comment: If ngdocs isn't enough, I say dig through source code. That's what I do when I really want to get in depth with something

Comment: @peeskillet thanks. It's a good idea.